# Bot Service Migration: 500 Server Error

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I've received multiple emails to migrate my bot, but every attempt I've made to upgrade using the Migrate link spends a ton of time processing, then fails with the error: **"An error occurred: 500
An internal error occurred at the server."**

The bot in question is an App Service based Bot Framework bot using Continuous Integration. It's functional in Skype at present and has been running without errors for several months. **The bot does NOT use the soon-to-be-deprecated state service.**

All previous examples of this issue occurring seem to be dated prior to the GA of the Bot Service, when Web App migrations were disabled. However, all official MSFT documentation claims that all migrations are enabled.

What are the actions I can take to get this bot migrated?

(error screenshot)
[image: 1]

Comment: Have you tried migrating from dev.botframework.com?

Comment: No, I hadn't - but just sat through the process from the site you suggested and got the same exact outcome. 500 server error after hanging during the migrating files step. :/

Still blocked. Is there any better guidance from the team? This seems like a pretty terrible interaction cliff: "Migration is mandatory but the errors aren't actionable so your bots are going to stop working."

Comment: We have some workaround steps on the troubleshooting doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems#why-cant-i-migrate-my-bot  Does this help?

Comment: Hi, sorry about the inconvenience, we're looking into this, and we'll let you know ASAP what we find. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Eric - sadly the workaround doesn't seem relevant (I don't have another user to add at present.)

Thanks for the update Andrea. Please let me know if you need more information to troubleshoot the problem (internal alias cplatz@). This repeatedly failed migration is still a blocker for my team's work moving forward with Bot Service.